# Custom Admin controller not displaying in magento

Tags: magento-1.6, php-5.4

I have created easylife admincontroller and it configure the config.xml, and I give the Url-> protocal://Ipaddress/ics/admin/admintest but it's not displaying.

can any one tell me where I went wrong?

my code is:

Ics->EasyLife->controllers->Adminhtml->IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Ics_EasyLife_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Ics->EasyLife->Block->Adminhtml->Template.php

```
<?php
class Ics_EasyLife_Block_Adminhtml_Template extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    public function MyMethod()
    {
        echo "Admin Html Page Method";
    }
}
```

Ics->EasyLife->etc->config.xml

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <icscontroller>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ics_EasyLife</module>
                    <frontName>admintest</frontName>
                </args>
            </icscontroller>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using "easylife" instead of "icscontroller" in config xml?

Answer (score 6):

I don't like that method of providing your own `frontName`, I prefer to [overload the existing admin router](http://www.knectar.com/labs/definitive-magento-controller-admin-pages) because it's neat and quick. Start by changing this in your config.xml:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <ics_easylife before="Mage_Adminhtml">Ics_EasyLife_Adminhtml</ics_easylife>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

This will make magento check for controller classes that start with `Ics_EasyLife_Adminhtml` before checking it's own `Mage_Adminhtml`.  Rename your controller to `Ics_EasyLife_Adminhtml_EasylifeController` and rename it's corresponding file to `EasylifeController.php`.

Now an URL of `adminhtml/easylife` will expand to `http://ipaddress/ics/admin/easylife/index` and call your `indexAction` method. When making a menu entry use that URL of `adminhtml/easylife`.  Even if you don't have any layout or blocks in place yet at least a page will show.  When writing a layout use the layout handle `<adminhtml_easylife_index>`.

Comment: Does the whitespace not break the parsing of the text node into module directory arguments?

Comment: @benmarks I didn't think so but after experimenting I see you were right.